# Is this Mongo query the same as this SQL query? Am I thinking about Mongo correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb

This isn't meant to be negative as I have been reading the Mongo documents.  I am new to the concept.  Mongo is touted as this ultra efficent database that is killing MySQL, but all the Mongo statements I read seem to be reducable to and thus no more efficent SQL.  Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach.

Let's say you have two tables:

```
User

ID    Name    FavoriteColor
1     John    1
2     Jona    2
3     Jack    1

Color

ID    Name
1     Red
2     Green
3     Blue
```

To get the user's colors I would do

```
SELECT
  `u`.`Name`,
  `c`.`color`
FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `color` AS `c` ON `u`.`FavoriteColor` = `c`.`id`
```

Not sure if that syntax is correct, I don't have MySQL in front of me.

Now Mongo doesn't support joins (people say that's the point of Mongo) so if I were to do this I would iterate the users collection and for each record I would then query the colors database against that user's favorite color ID and "iterate" the colors collection (should just return one row).  But this seems to be the exact same thing as (in PHP):

```
<?
        $query = "SELECT `Name`, `FavoriteColor` FROM `users`";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             $username = $row["Name"];
             $query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `Color` WHERE `id` = " . $row["FavoriteColor"] . " LIMIT 1";
             $result = mysql_query($query);
             $color = "";
             //I know we return only one row but I am illustrating the concept of scanning the entire color table
             while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  $color = $row2["Name"];
             }

             echo "Hi I'm $username and my favorite color is $color <br>";
        }
?>
```

From an efficiency standpoint I can't see how MongoDB can get any faster than SQL (join or the php iterated way still seems to be the same thing).  In the end of the day it has to scan the entire user table and FOR EACH user it has to scan the entire color table to match the colorID to the favorite color.

Should I be trying to logically reduce MongoDB stores down row\colums\tables, or does MongoDB inherently perform differently?

Comment: Here's a +1 from me for a very well placed question. Now I just need to wait for a Mongo zealot to try and explain this without digging his own grave :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about lack of join support in MongoDb. It allows MongoDB collection to be automatically distributed without risk to be asked for join between two distributed collections(tables). If it were possible, it would lead to a lot of work on servers and would not be scalable at all.

So it doesn't support joins, but it is document oriented database and it supports embedded documents. It affects database structure design dramatically. Now you have choice whether to embed or to create new collection(table) and concrete choice depends on data itself and data usage pattern, so you need to know your data usage patterns unfront.
Going back to your example, these two tables potentially could be merged in one collection `user` and you could have something like this:

```
{
  name: John,
  favoriteColor: Red
}
```

In this case there is no joins needed to retrieve the same data. It is completely different structure design. However, MongoDB doesn't support constraints( except uniqueness) and you need to take care that you don't try to use not existing color. For this you could have separate `color` collection and check the data when you insert data into collection `user`.

**Wrap-up:** efficiency of MongoDB is not in doing the same operations faster, but in ability to use different paradigm to model old problems.

Comment: I could have just put "Red" in the SQL user table also, but sometimes people have two tables because let's say Red, Green, and Blue are the only available colors.  I have a separate table for them so that I can just query that to populate a dropdown or something.  In MongoLand would you just do what you described then just have a seperate collection for available colors?

Comment: You still would have separate collection for color in MongoDB, if you need to constraint values. There is no black magic here. And you could put Red in SQL user table as well( although it would break normalization). But let's go beyond that simple example and imagine user could have multiple different colors and also could have some preferences and also could have some settings. In MongoDb you could have all this stuff in one document with rich options to query along and in addition if could have durability via replica sets and distribution via shards.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to understand MongoDb, you need to try to strip your mind from what you have learned with RDBMS.

MongoDB is a "dynamic schema" system, a document-based database that revolves around the data of objects notion.

In the example you posted, the structure you are using is still implementing more of a relational database approach to your design. For the sake of scaling of complex data and speed of development, and keeping in mind that there is no Join Support, I suggest you revisit your design and "de-normalize" your collections even if you think it might look redundant ( based on how databases have been designed for the past 40 years)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Mongo might be killing MYSQL but its not even close to MYSQL.

```
User

ID    Name    FavoriteColor
1     John    RED
2     Jona    GREEN
3     Jack    RED
```

That is how your data might look in mongo. Mongo does not support joins but supports embedded docs. You are always advised to place data into single collection in mongo if you are going to query that data frequently. In short there wil be no color table / collection. Most likely, the query to get user and color would be

```
db.collection.find({},{name:1,favoriteColor:1})
```

and your collection docs would be something like below.

```
{
  id: 1
  name: John
  FavCol: RED
}
```

Comment: You are aware that this isn't answering the question in slightest?

Comment: I won't try to explain the question to you, but you basically repeated what the OP mentioned in his post. It's simply silly to leave this as an answer.

Comment: @N.B. I do not need explanation from you either and its better you read it 10 to 15 times, probably you will get some idea :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: It appears there's too large of a language barrier here, I'll just let you wage your internet war with invisible enemies and purple unicorns.